# scanning only works under "sudo"

Tags: ubuntu, scanner

When I try to scan, using simple-scan, the UI says `Failed to scan -- Unable to connect to scanner`.  When I run it from the command line I get:

```
joel@home:/usr/bin$ simple-scan -d
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: Starting Simple Scan 2.32.0.1, PID=6554
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: Restoring window to 600x400 pixels
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: sane_init () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: SANE version 1.0.22
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: Requesting redetection of scan devices
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: Processing request
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: Requesting scan at 300 dpi from device '(null)'
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: scanner_scan ("(null)", 300, SCAN_SINGLE)
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: sane_get_devices () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: Device: name="brother2:bus4;dev1" vendor="Brother" model="MFC-210C" type="USB scanner"
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: Processing request
** (simple-scan:6554): DEBUG: sane_open ("brother2:bus4;dev1") -> SANE_STATUS_IO_ERROR

** (simple-scan:6554): WARNING **: Unable to get open device: Error during device I/O
```

FYI, I have already done:

```
joel@home:~$ sudo chmod a+rwx /dev/bus/usb
joel@home:~$ sudo chmod a+rwx /dev/bus/usb/*
```

If I run under `sudo`:

```
joel@home:~$ sudo simple-scan
```

it works.

How can I get simple-scan to work without sudo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chances are that `saned` doesn't think you're allowed to connect to it.  See the [Permissions Issues](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo#Permission_Issues) section of the Ubuntu Scanning How-to for details.

Comment: Seems that all user accounts aren't added to the scanner group. I used `sudo adduser username scanner` and then you need to log off and back in again for the group membership to be noticed by the OS.

Comment: Did not work for me. I seem to remember that the only way to do it was using sudo and a text version not simple scan. Will keep looking

Comment: KayEss's suggestion ("sudo adduser username scanner") worked for my Raspbian install.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem (Ubuntu 11.04 - Natty Narwhal): Scanning as root works fine, scanning as user – no go. `scanimage -L` and `sane-find-scanner` found and identified the the scanner correctly, even when run as normal user. `simple-scan -d both as root and normal user didn't show up anything useful in terms of missing group right, missing files or drivers.

Eventually [this link worked for me](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Brother/Scanner).

The solution was editing these files:

- `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules`
- `/etc/udev/rules.d/55-libsane.rules`

Not sure if both needed to be edited, I applied all changes as described. Very important: REBOOT after editing.

Answer (score 3):

> sudo adduser YOURNONROOTUSERNAME lp

to make sure scanner belongs to **lp** group:

> sudo sane-find-scanner
>
> found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9, product=0x02a5) at libusb:**001:002**
>
> ls -al /dev/bus/usb/**001/002**
>
> crw-rw-r-- 1 root **lp** 189, 1 Nov 24 12:43 /dev/bus/usb/001/002

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding this line to `/etc/rc.local` (before `exit 0`):

```
chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb
```

and editing/creating the following 2 files:

`/etc/xinetd.d/saned`:

```
service saned 
{
socket_type = stream
server = /usr/sbin/saned
protocol = tcp
user = root
group = root
wait = no
disable = no
}
```

`/etc/default/saned`:

```
# Defaults for the saned initscript, from sane-utils

# Set to yes to start saned
RUN=yes

# Set to the user saned should run as
RUN_AS_USER=root
```

then rebooting.

It's working, but I still would like a more secure way of solving this.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the following:

```
/etc/default/saned
```

And change the:

```
RUN_AS_USER=saned
```

to

```
RUN_AS_USER=root
```

Restart and test again – this should be working.

Comment: Something tells me this is not a desirable solution from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your username to the **lp** group and then reboot (or `sudo ldconfig`). Everything should be working.

This worked for me because if you run `lsusb` to grab the USB bus number of your printer/scanner (mine was 005) and then `ll /dev/bus/usb/005` you will see that **root** is the owner and **lp** is the group, both have read and write permissions.

Comment: how do you `add your username to the lp group `?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and this work for me and it is as simple as that. I actually copied from the Brother Website that solved my scanner problems:

1. Open `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules` file.
2. Add the following two lines to the end of the device list. (Before the line `# The following rule will disable ...`):

   `# Brother scanners`

   `ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with my Epson EcoTank 2500. 
I went into the terminal and found the product id with `lsusb`.
For the EcoTank 2500 it's 1105.

Then

```
Open /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules file.
```

I then searched for that product id with gedit and couldn't find it. So I added onto the bottom (leaving a space and writing it in CAPS so I know that it was me that changed it!)

```
# MY EPSON ECOTANK ET-2500

ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1105", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
```

I then did the same in 40-iscan.rules  (it's in the same folder)
Finally I rebooted.
Hey presto....ahhhh! My work here is done.

Answer (score 0):

All other solutions did not work for me. The issue for me (Xubuntu 18.04) was the fact, that the user was not allowed to access /dev/bus/usb/. Unfortunately, you won't really get a error message telling you this.

This can be tested by running `strace xsane 2>&1 | grep EACCES | sort -u` with the user account. After exiting xsane, you will get access errors. In contrast to other solutions, the devices `ls -al /dev/bus/usb/001/002` belonged to `root:root` and not `root:lp`, so adding the user to `lp` did nothing.

Run `sudo chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb` to grant access and try again. If `scanimage -L` now works, you have to make sure to apply this after every reboot.

On newer Debian/Ubuntus you have to create the file `/etc/rc.local` since it might not exist. Set `chmod +x /etc/rc.local`, open the file as root and add the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
chmod -R a+w /dev/bus/usb
exit 0
```

Then, since modern Ubuntu/Debian uses Systemd, you can check the script with `systemctl status rc-local.service`. In case rc.local is not used, check [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd) link. Reboot to test.